# In pgAdmin, when creating a new connection why is the password field for SSH tunnel greyed out?

Tags: pgadmin-4

I'm registering a new server in pgAdmin desktop client for Windows. In the SSH Tunnel tab, the "Save password?" field is greyed out, even when I've filled in all of the fields. Why is this?

[image]

Extra details:

- I've set a master password for the app
- When I click save, it connects fine, but on restarting pgAdmin and entering my master password, when I connect to this server again I'm asked to enter the SSH key password again. The "Save Password" field is also greyed out in this dialogue.
- I couldn't find any help in the documentation about why this field might be greyed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your user config file (which could be for example in `/usr/pgadmin4/web/config_local.py`) create a line that looks like this:

```
ALLOW_SAVE_TUNNEL_PASSWORD = True  # SSH tunnel password saving, default False
```

For more details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65603688/pgadmin-failed-to-save-password-for-users/74721798#74721798).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).